# Group By in mongoengine EmbeddedDocumentListField

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine, embedded-documents

Hi so I have this test data in mongo for mongoengine that I use for storing user's cart:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55e492ac516ddc17a8b07d2a"),
    "user" : ObjectId("55e3f236516ddc78296968be"),
    "items" : [
        {
            "item" : ObjectId("55e24cd6516ddcbdc081842b"),
            "quantity" : 2,
            "added_date" : ISODate("2015-08-31T17:44:49.023Z")
        },
        {
            "item" : ObjectId("55e24cd6516ddcbdc0818425"),
            "quantity" : 3,
            "added_date" : ISODate("2015-08-31T17:44:49.025Z")
        },
        {
            "item" : ObjectId("55e24cd6516ddcbdc0818420"),
            "quantity" : 3,
            "added_date" : ISODate("2015-08-31T17:44:49.026Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Here the models:

```
class CartItem(mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument):
    item = mongoengine.ReferenceField('Item')
    quantity = mongoengine.IntField()
    added_date = mongoengine.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())

class Cart(mongoengine.Document):
    user = mongoengine.ReferenceField('User')
    items = mongoengine.EmbeddedDocumentListField(CartItem)
```

Here I store items in user's cart. Now I would like to get all the unique items in the items list field because there will be duplicate items.

I perform the following queries to get the items:

```
cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=user).first()
queryset = cart.items
```

In this case I think I would have to group the items, I tried using  raw query in filter : `cart.items.filter(__raw__...)`  But this just doesn't work because raw is not supported in this case. Can someone please help me in how I can do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can **use [`.distinct()`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.distinct) to get all the unique values** of `items` instead of doing `groupby`.

> Return a list of distinct values for a given field.

You need to do something like:

```
unique_items = Cart.objects.filter(user=user).first().distinct('items')
```

This will return a list of unique `items` in a cart for a particular user.

**EDIT:**

If you want a unique list of `item` field inside the `items` embedded document field, then you need to use dot `.` to go to that field.

```
Cart.objects.filter(user=user).first().distinct('items.item')
```

Comment: That's great! Thanks! The only thing I changed is  .distinct('items.item')

Comment: Glad to help! I have included the same in the ans.

Comment: @RahulGupta - How can we sort the result set while making distinct ?